# Equivalence of norms on a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Two norms $\|.\|_1$ , $\|.\|_2$ defined on a normed linear space N are such  that **N forms a Banach space** with respect to both the norms.**Then $||.||_1$ and $||.||_2$ are equivalent** if and only if 
    $\tau_{||.||_1}$ $\subseteq$ $\tau_{||.||_2}$
where $\tau_{||.||_1}$ and $\tau_{||.||_2}$ are topologies induced by $||.||_1$ and $||.||_2$ respectively.

I presume that this could be a consequence of OPEN MAPPPING THEOREM, but I am having problem in showing the ***incomparability of the topologies***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[$\Rightarrow$] Let $(N,\|.\|_1)$ be equivalent to $(N,\|.\|_2)$. Then it follows that the identity map $I: (N,\|.\|_1) \rightarrow (N,\|.\|_2)$ is a homeomorphism: it clearly is linear and bijective, and the condition of equivalent norms is equivalent to $I$ and $I^{-1}$ being bounded. Consequently, 
$$I(\tau_{\|.\|_1}) \subseteq \tau_{\|.\|_2}.$$

[$\Leftarrow$] Let $\tau_{||.||_1} \subseteq \tau_{||.||_2}$. Then, $I^{-1}$ as defined above continuous and therefore, bounded. By the open mapping theorem, it is a homeomorphism, which implies that $I$ is bounded.